# "table view does not exist" error while using external tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using below code to insert data into main table using external table  but i am getting below error

```
declare
v_file varchar2(50):= 'abc.txt';
v_badfile varchar2(50) := 'test.bad';
v_logfile varchar2(50) :=  'test.log';
begin
execute immediate'create table ext_tab2 (
mprn number,
post_code varchar2(8),
house_no varchar2(8),
market_sector_flag varchar2(1),
ssc varchar2(3),
dcv  number )
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    LOAD WHEN
         (mprn  != BLANKS) AND
         (post_code != BLANKS) AND
         (house_no != BLANKS) 
    BADFILE IMPORT_PPM:'''||v_badfile||'''
    LOGFILE IMPORT_PPM:'''||v_logfile||''' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '''||','||''' 
    )  
    LOCATION  ('''||v_file||''')
    )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';   

insert into table_1 select * from ext_tab2;
EXECUTE immediate' drop table ext_tab2';
end;
```

**table1** has  same column as ext_tab2 .   I am getting error for **ext_tab2** - table doesnot exist.
can any one help me on this .

Comment: Is the external table even getting created? Remove the drop statement, and first check whether it's created or not.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - it won't be created because the compilation error means the whole block is not executed; removing the drop won't show any difference here as it'll still fail to compile because of the invalid insert statement.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Well that is what I meant to tell OP, but sarcastically.

Answer (score 4):

You're creating the table dynamically, so when the PL/SQL block is compiled it does not yet exist. Because compilation fails, none of the statements are executed anyway.

If you must create the table dynamically, you have to refer to it dynamically as well:

```
execute immediate 'insert into table_1 select * from ext_tab';
```

You should avoid creating objects at runtime wherever possible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

ext_tab2 is created only in runtime, so compiler doesn't know about it. You should try to put your insert statement in Execute immediate as well.